# Android Sliding Up Panel (Activity)

Tags: android

I have seen something like [this](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) in lollipop version of android.It is in contacts app of lollipop version of sony's rom.When you tap on a contacts name an activity(I say activity because it has a separate toolbar) comes from bottom and you can drag it up or down to close is. I don't know the exact name of this control but It seems to be an activity and works exactly similar to Sliding Up Panel that I linked in my question.
Now I want to know is there any standard(googles recommended) way (something like appcompact which is used to bring material into pre lollipop versions and also works fine with lollipop) to achieve this propose?

I have searched a little and found [android.support.v4.widget.slidingpanelayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) Can I use this for my purpose?
Thank you so much

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I use Umano's Android Sliding Up Panel

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel